Master Key/Certificate for encyption tenant kek/dek keys
I'm building multi-tenant solution (not in cloud) where we need to store sensitive data which should be encrypted. Some of our clients want to bring own keys (BYOK).
Each tenant has own instance of application and database. There is no tenant data in any shared place.
So tenant can upload own keys which should be secured (encrypted) with... And that is the question - I'm not a Cryptography expert.
Can we use something called Master Key/Certificate where each tenant instance will have own - for eg. generated and securely stored by some KMS at the registration phase?
